# Deep Search on Tree - JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I am trying to create a deepSearch method using pseudoclassical method that traverses the tree where in each node's value creates a new tree with the result that has the same structure and containing result.

```
For instance:
  var root1 = new Tree(1);
  var branch2 = root1.addChild(2);
  var branch3 = root1.addChild(3);
  var leaf4 = branch2.addChild(4);
  var leaf5 = branch2.addChild(5);
  var leaf6 = branch3.addChild(6);
  var leaf7 = branch3.addChild(7);
  var newTree = root1.deepSearch(function (value) {
    return value * 2;
  })

  newTree.value // 2
  newTree.children[0].value // 4
  newTree.children[1].value // 6
  newTree.children[0].children[1].value // 10
  newTree.children[1].children[1].value // 14
   root1.value // still 1
```

Right now here's my function.

```
var deepSearch = function(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];

};

deepSearch.prototype.addChild = function(value){
    var child = new deepSearch(value);
  this.children.push(child);
  return child;
};

deepSearch.prototype.map = function(val, cb){
  if(this.value === val){
    cb(this.value);
 }


 if(this.children){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
    if(this.children[i].contains(val)){
      cb(this.value);
    }
  }
 }

 return false;
};
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are calling the callback, but the resulting value is never assigned back to `this.value`

Comment: How do I execute it then with the recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a recursive map call:

```js
class Tree {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild(value) {
    var child = new Tree(value);
    this.children.push(child);
    return child;
  } 

  map(callback) {
    function mapNode(node, copy, callback) {
      for (let child of node.children)
        mapNode(child, copy.addChild(callback(child.value)), callback);
    }

    var copy = new Tree(callback(this.value));
    mapNode(this, copy, callback);
    return copy;
  }
}

  var root1 = new Tree(1);
  var branch2 = root1.addChild(2);
  var branch3 = root1.addChild(3);
  var leaf4 = branch2.addChild(4);
  var leaf5 = branch2.addChild(5);
  var leaf6 = branch3.addChild(6);
  var leaf7 = branch3.addChild(7);
  var newTree = root1.map(function (value) {
    return value * 2;
  })

console.log(
  newTree.value, // 2
  newTree.children[0].value, // 4
  newTree.children[1].value, // 6
  newTree.children[0].children[1].value, // 10
  newTree.children[1].children[1].value, // 14
   root1.value // still 1
)
```